# How to find symbolic greatest common divisor?

Tags: symbolic

How can I use Mathematica to find the greatest common divisor of symbols? For example, is there some way that I could input $GCD[a,a+ba]$ and have Mathematica output $a$ as the greatest common divisor?

Comment: Check documentation for `PolynomialGCD`.